# Syntax error (TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, syntax-error

Where I am going wrong in syntax?

```
vif_cal(input_data=dataset(['a','b','c'], axis=1), 
dependent_col='d')
```

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling dataframe as a function which is not callable. Try using this way:

```
vif_cal(input_data=dataset[['a','b','c']], dependent_col='d')
```